# Does Allah accept duas againt people?

Tags: allah, dua

if someone did a dua against themselves then they regretted doing the dua.Will Allah accept it or deny it because the person felt regret and he's sorry?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered by the community, which means **it is now a community work**. If you think this question should be deleted, you are more than welcome to discuss it on [meta] where the community can be involved in the decision. **You do not get to unilaterally decide to undo everybody else's work by deleting, destroying or changing this question just because you no longer like it.**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible that Allah might accept a dua against someone. In the hadeeth it says:

> “Do not pray against yourselves, do not pray against your children, and do not pray against your wealth, lest that coincide with an hour when Allaah is asked and He answers your prayers.” Narrated by Muslim (3009).

In regards to being forgiven for that bad du'a. We should never lose hope in Allah's mercy as His mercy encompasses all things. So if you were to sincerely repent to Him feeling regretful and doing everything in your power to change for the best then He will forgive you, in shaa Allah.

Allah knows best

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the above question, a question may arise whether one can make a dua against someone who has wronged them in some way. The short answer to this question is although it is better to forgive the person, it is also acceptable to make dua against them.

Consider the following two ahadith.

Abu Hurayra reported that the Prophet (may Allah bless him and grant him peace), said:

> “There are three supplications which are answered: the supplication of the person who is wronged, the supplication of the traveler, and the supplication of a parent for his child. [Al-Adab Al-Mufrad]

Also, it was narrated that ‘Abdullah bin Sarjis said:

> “When the Prophet (peace be upon him) traveled, he would seek refuge with Allah from the hardships of travel, and the sorrows of return, from loss after plenty, from the supplication of the one who has been wronged, and from seeing some calamity befall.” [Sunan an-Nasa’i]

So the supplication of the one who has been wronged is both acceptable as powerful. It would be wise not to make a dua that retaliates an injustice with a greater injustice. In addition, be careful make a dua against family member or a loved one as you may feel guilty later if you make amends with the person.

In addition, Allah says in the Quran:

> {And the retribution for an evil act is an evil one like it, but whoever pardons and makes reconciliation – his reward is [due] from Allah. Indeed, He does not like wrongdoers.And whoever avenges himself after having been wronged – those have not upon them any cause [for blame].The cause is only against the ones who wrong the people and tyrannize upon the earth without right. Those will have a painful punishment.And whoever is patient and forgives – indeed, that is of the matters [requiring] determination.And he whom Allah sends astray – for him there is no protector beyond Him. And you will see the wrongdoers, when they see the punishment, saying, “Is there for return [to the former world] any way?} [Quran 42: 40-44]

As Muslims, we have a right to seek justice when we are wronged, but if are patient and decide to forgive [in certain cases], then the reward from Allah is unlimited and the person who does that has their status elevated.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

If that person is genuinely sorry from heart and repents sincerely.Allah can listen even through heartbeats so if its a genuine feeling to be sorry then he will.Allah wil listen to that person if their intentions are pure and they consider that thing as a bad thing which they had done in past.Allah knows best.Jazakallah